# Defining a range in a function with the value in a cell instead of a range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function

I have the following table and I'm trying to write a formula that will take the value of column C and put it into the COUNTIF function where the ?? is.

```
A                     B                         C
Data Label            Data Range                Name
----------            ----------                ----------
Label#1               =countif(data!??,A1)      A1:B
Label#2               =countif(data!??,A2)      C1:D
Label#3               =countif(data!??,A3)      E1:F
```

I have hundreds of rows and dozens of columns and I'm trying to avoid manually update the target range for the COUNTIF.

I've tried `=countif(data!&C1,A1)` and `=countif(data!&"C1",A1)` and `=countif(data!C1,A1)`, but none work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) to get a cell reference by a string, which in your case is coming from a cell.  To use the range as defined in cell C2 but refer to a sheet called data, use:

```
=countif(INDIRECT("data!"&C2, TRUE),A2)
```

Hopefully I understand the final formula correctly.  If not, replace the range reference with the INDIRECT() function.  If this does not work, first check your formula with a manual entry of the range.  If that works, there is a syntax issue with the INDIRECT() function so try putting

```
=INDIRECT(C2, TRUE)
```

in a cell and see what is returned to check that as well.